# how to writea a select query based on ranks?

Tags: sql

i have one table

table1

```
id   city    projects       Rank
----------------------------------
1    che        p2           2
2    bang       p1           1
3    che        p4           1
4    bang       p3           2
5    bang       p5           3
6    gur        p6           1
7    gur        p7           2
```

based on rank i want to select city and project
i want like this

```
   bang       p1            1
    che        p4           1
    gur        p6           1
    che        p2           2
    bang       p3           2
    gur        p7           2
    bang       p5           3
```

select * from table1 where Rank = ?

Comment: Don't you think it would make sense to read at least the first few lines of an introduction to sql before asking questions?

Answer (score 2):

```
select city,project,rank from table1 order by rank,project,city
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help you:

```
select city, projects, Rank from table1 
order by Rank, city, projects
```

you can also use positions in `order by` clause:

```
select city, projects, Rank from table1 
order by 3,1,2
```

Solution with `0` on the bottom:

```
 select city, projects, Rank from table1 
    order by
    case 
     when Rank>0 then 1
     else 2
    end,
    Rank, city, projects
```

Comment: but i have one more problem in rank list contain 0 value it want to show last

Comment: @Athi I added one more solution.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 select city, projects, Rank from table order by Rank
```

Answer (score 1):

use `ORDER BY` clause in your query.

```
SELECT city, projects, rank FROM table1 
order by rank
```

Answer (score 1):

Many answers here are fine.

However it is common practice to use UPPERCASE for language constructs in SQL:

```
SELECT city,project,rank FROM table1 ORDER BY rank,project;
```

:-)

Comment: @hd1: I have to admit, you are right! Actually the sql standard does _not_ state that. It is just common practice to use upper case to improve readability of the structure of statements. I corrected the answer. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
select city,projects,rank from table1 group by rank order by rank,city,projects;
```

Comment: Your answer would be considerably better if you could explain _why_ this would work.

Comment: u output three rows. he wanted 7